# Java Swing accordion in Nimbus look and feel

Tags: java, swing, nimbus, expandable

While I was reading Oracle Swing documentation, I came across [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html) of a set of components displaying the Nimbus Look and Feel named `SwingSet3`. I'm new to Swing. Can someone tell me if the accordion in the sidebar is a Swing component or not?

[image: SwingSet3]

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html
the image link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a standard swing component.

You can have a look at the source code for the SwingSet3 demo [here](http://java.net/projects/swingset3/sources/svn/show/trunk/SwingSet3/src). The component on the left is a composite component made out of various other components such as `JPanel`, `JLabel` and `JButton`. There is a custom [`com.sun.swingset3.utilities.CollapsiblePanel`](http://java.net/projects/swingset3/sources/svn/content/trunk/SwingSet3/src/com/sun/swingset3/utilities/CollapsiblePanel.java?rev=219) too.

Comment: true - but (biased :-) me wouldn't recommend using it as it's a) demo code b) unmaintained

Answer (score 3):

A similar component is the JXTaskPane/-Container which is part of [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net) You can have a [look at a demo](http://swinglabs-demos.java.net/demos/swingxset6/swingxset.jnlp) inspired by SwingSet3.

Note that SwingX is actively maintained, its current release 1.6.3 available at maven.java.net

Comment: Thanks for the link.   I was also comparing this to the JavaFX Accordion class.  Both the JXTaskPane and the swingset3 CollapsiblePanel seem superior to me, at the moment, than the JavaFX Accordion because it, strangely, only allows one sub-component to be open at a time.

Comment: @Enwired they are different components: an accordion (or outlook bar) is designed to show exactly one page, just as a tabbedPane. BTW (cough): the 1.6.3 release of SwingX has a show-stopper bug regarding JXCollapsible/JXTaskPane (http://java.net/jira/browse/SWINGX-1494). On the bright side: it is fixed in the svn version.