# Java JTable Expand Collapse Behaviour

Tags: java, swing, jtable, accordion, jtreetable

Can anybody please point me the direction, how I can achieve below behavious using JTable?

http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/expandable-rows/

I need some sample code to make image clickable(changing Expand/Collpase images) in the cell.

Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=[java]%20swing%20accordion

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Swing accordion in Nimbus look and feel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030002/java-swing-accordion-in-nimbus-look-and-feel), in particular [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10042185/829571).

Comment: @assylias maybe not duplicate (how I can achieve below behavious using JTable) ???

Comment: @mKorbel & assylias - Thanks for your comments. But I need Expand Collpase behaviour for JTable. Specially some sample code, to start with, where clicking on "+" image will change to "-" image and expand/show the row details.

Comment: The javaScript code you point to, which is really nice, achieves part of the trick by setting `colspan=4` on the table cell.  You can't easily do that with a JTable.  See question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199392/jtable-row-span-and-column-span

Answer (score 3):

> point me the direction, how I can achieve below behavious using JTable?

have look at (died project) [JTreeTable](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/treetable1/), excelent workaround by

- [customizations by aephyr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517974/714968)
- [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net/)
- [OutLine by NetBeans](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui#6182305)
- [non Free by Jide](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/grids.htm)

Comment: Indeed. SwingX has a `JXTreeTable` which allows to do this

Comment: @Robin naturally delighted by your trust in the omni-potence of SwingX :-) But the sample linked to by the OP cannot be achieved with JXTreeTable nor by any of the other links provided here except JIDE (their component is called HierarchicalTable)

Comment: @kleopatra Time to log an enhancement request then :-) . I was pretty sure that it was possible but I did not try it. Luckily you came by to correct my assumption

Comment: @both I don't know how, where and what.. if is that possible in SwingX (treecellrenderer), but aephyr override treecellrenderer and/or with block for tablecellrenderer